# ManyToMany jpa - Spring Salvar dados entidade de relacionamento

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

Boa noite galera!
Tenho 2 classes: Serviços e Pedido.
Serviços contem nome e valor/hora.
Pedido contem  os atributos: valorBruto, valorLiquido, percentualImposto , usuario e uma lista de serviços.

fiz uma relação many to many gerando uma 3° tabela pedido_servicos;

estou fazendo com base nesse exercicio:

> O sistema deverá ter uma página para cadastramento dos Serviços (nome do serviço e valor de hora para venda);
> O sistema deverá ter uma página para cadastramento do Pedido de Serviço, onde deverá ser informado: (s) serviço(s) a ser(em) comercializado(s); quantidade de horas de cada serviço;
> O profissional que será alocado para execução desse Pedido de Serviço;
> O % de imposto da venda que será adicionado ao valor final do pedido.
> Ao salvar o Pedido, exibir em uma caixa de diálogo mostrando o valor total do pedido e o % de lucro desse pedido para a empresa.

a dúvida é, como faço para adicionar mais campos na tabela pedido_servicos para pesistir quando salvar um pedido?

Exemplo: objeto que imagino pra salvar é parecido com algo assim:

```
{
   valorBruto: 50,
   valorLiquido: 40,
   percentualImposto: 10,
   usuario: "teste",
   imposto: 10,
   servicos: [{
        idServico: 1,
        qtdHora: 40
   }]
}
```

O problema é que quando tento salvar o pedido, ele tenta salvar o relacionamento pedido_servico que tem o atributo qtde_hora e esta nulo e ocorre o erro.

Segue o código das classes.

Pedido

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
public class Pedido {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_pedido")
    private Long idPedido;
    @Column(name = "valor_total_bruto", nullable = false)
    private double valorTotalBruto;
    @Column(name = "valor_total_liquido", nullable = false)
    private double valorTotalLiquido;
    @Column(name = "perc_imposto", nullable = false)
    private double percentualImposto;
    @Column(name = "usuario", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String usuario;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "pedido_servico", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_pedido") },             
         inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_servico") })
    private List<Servico> servicos;
}
```

Serviço

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "servico")
public class Servico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_servico")
    private long idServico;
    @Column(name = "nome_servico", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String nomeServico;
    @Column(name = "valor_hora", nullable = false)
    private double valorHora;
}
```

PedidoServico

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido_servico")
public class PedidoServico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_pedido_servico")
    private long idPedidoServico;
    @Column(name = "qtd_hora", nullable = false)
    private int qtdHora;
    @Column(name = "id_servico", nullable = false)
    private long idServico;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite Fabio ! Pelo que entendi do problema neste caso você não precisa desta terceira classe "PedidoServico". Outra detalhe no caso seria um pedido ter varios serviço ne ? no caso deve usar o @OneToMany

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="servicos_id", nullable=false)
private List<Servico> servicos;
```

Um ultimo detalhe na classe Serviços o campo nomeServiço esta como nulllable=false, então você deve passar um valor, ou alterar para nullable=true

Comment: Opa Renan, muito obrigado pela resposta, no fim era exatamente isso, obrigado mesmo :D